# Recording video HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, web-deployment

I want to be able to record videos with audio using HTML and Javascript.

After some research i can get video streaming with getUserMedia. Also There is WebRTC for recording but as far as i understood its not yet implemented in desktop browsers (only mobile browsers support it). So now i can just capture video, but i cant save it to server or record it.

What other options do i have ?. Does anyone knows a good flash alternative or HTML5 alternative that allows me to capture and save video to server with audio and also has maximum time of recording

Comment: Actually Chrome and Firefox [both support WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/), *right now*.

Comment: Provide browser support constraints... WebTv, ie6 etc... :)

Comment: Kyle Kelley http://www.webrtc.org/chrome says that recording is not fully implemented yet.

Comment: Ted Johnson Firefox, chrome, safari mainly

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure: I work for Ziggeo.

When it comes to WebRTC, here is the rundown for browsers supporting it:

- on Chrome and Opera, you have to record audio and video separately and encode them yourself in JS; then, send them to your servers and transcode them using e.g. ffmpeg to mp4s and other target formats
- on Firefox, you can get a webm object for video and audio combined and send it to your servers.

For all other browsers and older versions of the ones mentioned you'd need to fall back to Flash recording which usually is based on RTMP and flv.